# How to update kernel version on Ubuntu 20.04 on a server setup such as Vultr

Tags: kernel, updates

I found a few entries in few forums, but am not convinced and comfortable to do this.
How would I update the kernel on a Virtual machine (Vultr) running Ubuntu "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS" safely.
Thanks in Advance
Ben

Comment: Generally you don't. You should never alter a virtual machine that you can not access if it does not boot for whatever reason. The better approach would be to create a NEW virtual machine with the version you want and transfer your personal data and settings.  Then when it all works you burn the old virtual machine. That way during every step of whatever you do you always have a working virtual machine to fall back on.

Comment: Well, what you say it does make sense, but acquiring a different VM changes the IP and moving the data, contacting the domain holder under that, it is a big job. Is there any other way? I know there is KernelCare, I am sure they do not do this!